# sklearn2pmml error: Java.lang.Unsupported ClassVersionError: com/sklearn2pmml/Main: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn2pmml

I'm trying to export a XGBoost model to PMML using sklearn2pmml and get the following error:

> sklearn2pmml (pipeline, "mymodel.pmml", with repr True)
>
> Error:
>
> Standard output is empty
> Standard error:
> java.lang.Unsupported ClassVersionError: com/sklearn2pmml/Main: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

The sklearn2pmml version is 0.94.1 and the scikit-learn version is 1.2.1
I have the same code running in another laptop without problems, the only difference I found is that in the laptop where the code runs has an older version of scikit-learn (1.1.1) and the same version of sklearn2pmml.
Is it possible that the error is related to the scikit-learn version or it is entirely another subject?

Comment: It is an error from the Java runtime. A class (probably in a JAR file) was compiled with a Java compiler version that is too new (or too old). Try to update your Java runtime (JRE).